# Activate GPS in BlackBerry 10 dev alpha

Tags: gps, wifi, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I want to activate GPS in BlackBerry 10 Dev aplha device. In my application I want the user's current position. I can achieve this using either GPS or Network Provider but there is no sim card in my device but wifi is activated.

How do I get the user's current position using either GPS or wifi network?

Comment: Please be more specific, are you on cascades/webworks/AIR/android runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the developers' site under [sample applications](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/sampleapps/), you will the [Location diagnostics](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/files/release/samples/platform/locationdiagnostics.zip) sample.

Comment: This is for cascades, the user tagged the question under android so this may not be what he wants.

Comment: Then the user should be more specific.

Comment: I want it in android application